# Why does my Kali Linux VM in VMware Workstation look like windows 10?

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, vmware

I have a Kali Linux VM and am using VMware. When I launch it, it looks like a Windows 10 desktop:

[image]

Any reason to why this would happen? The last time I launched this VM, everything was fine.

Comment: What ISO did you used to install Kali

Comment: I used an iso from the Kali website. I verified the hash. Earlier today, it launched with no problems. This is functional, but it just looks like a Windows 10 Desktop.

Comment: It is a Kali desktop setting as I posted .  It can be changed

Comment: Also you may have gotten stuck in terminal mode.   Update and restart

Answer (score 1):

I have a Kali VM on 2 different boxes, one using VMware Workstation.

Look carefully in Desktop and Appearance settings.

It appears you have set the Desktop to have a Windows 10 appearance .

Windows 10 theme both light and dark is one of the settings.

I use Windows 10 Light.

You can use what you wish .

Just look carefully around the settings

Also make sure Kali did not launch only in terminal mode,

Run updates and restart

sudo apt-get update followed by sudo apt-get upgrade

Restart and test

===================

You can test by spinning up a new machine. Make sure you have the ISO for making a real or VM machine.

Do a graphical installation, follow the prompts, be sure to install grub, if it needs a location use /dev/sda

I have been running Kali since V2019 and have gotten used to most of its quirks.

Comment: Ok, I didn't know if it was VMware where I needed to change this, or within the Kali box. I ran the command 'kali-undercover' and it switched the display back.

Comment: It is a graphical setting on the Kali desktop.  Update via terminal and restart to get the full Kali GUI back

Comment: You can test by spinning up a new machine. Make sure you have the ISO for making a real or VM machine. Do a graphical installation, follow the prompts, be sure to install grub, if it needs a location use /dev/sda